# background coloring wrong when hovering in with first column in TreeViewer

Tags: hover, swt, treeviewer

something strange happens when I switch-off the focus-coloring via `LabelProvider` and `event.detail &= ~SWT.HOT` and working with non-white background color.

Looks like only the non-text area in the first column becomes white when the mouse is over it (and text-color/foreground changes to blue?).

Any idea how I can get rid of it?

Attached a picture of the effect, source below.

[image: example]

```java
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Color;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Point;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.FillLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Event;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Listener;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Tree;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TreeColumn;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TreeItem;


public class testSwtTreeEvents {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
      Display display = new Display();
      Shell shell = new Shell(display);
      shell.setText("Multiple lines in a TreeItem");
      shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());
      final Tree tree = new Tree(shell, SWT.MULTI | SWT.FULL_SELECTION);
      tree.setHeaderVisible(true);
      tree.setLinesVisible(true);
      Color red = display.getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_RED);
      Color green = display.getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_GREEN);
      Color yellow = display.getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_YELLOW);

      int columnCount = 4;
      for (int i = 0; i < columnCount; i++) {
        TreeColumn column = new TreeColumn(tree, SWT.NONE);
        column.setText("Column " + i);
        column.setWidth(100);
      }
      int itemCount = 3;
      for (int i = 0; i < itemCount; i++) {
        TreeItem item1 = new TreeItem(tree, SWT.NONE);
        item1.setText("item " + i);
        item1.setBackground(red);
        for (int c = 1; c < columnCount; c++) {
          item1.setText(c, "item [" + i + "-" + c + "]");
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < itemCount; j++) {
          TreeItem item2 = new TreeItem(item1, SWT.NONE);
          item2.setText("item [" + i + " " + j + "]");
          item2.setBackground(green);
          for (int c = 1; c < columnCount; c++) {
            item2.setText(c, "item [" + i + " " + j + "-" + c + "]");
          }
          for (int k = 0; k < itemCount; k++) {
            TreeItem item3 = new TreeItem(item2, SWT.NONE);
            item3.setText("item [" + i + " " + j + " " + k + "]");
            item3.setBackground(yellow);
            for (int c = 1; c < columnCount; c++) {
              item3.setText(c, "item [" + i + " " + j + " " + k + "-" + c + "]");
            }
          }
        }
      }

      /*
       * NOTE: MeasureItem, PaintItem and EraseItem are called repeatedly.
       * Therefore, it is critical for performance that these methods be as
       * efficient as possible.
       */
      Listener paintListener = new Listener() {
        public void handleEvent(Event event) {
          switch (event.type) {
          case SWT.MeasureItem: {
            TreeItem item = (TreeItem) event.item;
            String text = getText(item, event.index);
            Point size = event.gc.textExtent(text);
            event.width = size.x;
            event.height = Math.max(event.height, size.y);
            break;
          }
          case SWT.PaintItem: {
            TreeItem item = (TreeItem) event.item;
            String text = getText(item, event.index);
            Point size = event.gc.textExtent(text);
            int offset2 = event.index == 0 ? Math.max(0, (event.height - size.y) / 2) : 0;
            event.gc.drawText(text, event.x, event.y + offset2, true);
            break;
          }
          case SWT.EraseItem: {
            event.detail &= ~SWT.FOREGROUND;
            event.detail &= ~SWT.HOT;
            event.detail &= ~SWT.SELECTED;
            break;
          }
          }
        }

        String getText(TreeItem item, int column) {
          String text = item.getText(column);
          if (column != 0) {
            TreeItem parent = item.getParentItem();
            int index = parent == null ? tree.indexOf(item) : parent.indexOf(item);
            if ((index + column) % 3 == 1) {
              text += "\nnew line";
            }
            if ((index + column) % 3 == 2) {
              text += "\nnew line\nnew line";
            }
          }
          return text;
        }
      };
      tree.addListener(SWT.MeasureItem, paintListener);
      tree.addListener(SWT.PaintItem, paintListener);
      tree.addListener(SWT.EraseItem, paintListener);

      shell.setSize(600, 400);
      shell.open();
      while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch())
          display.sleep();
      }
      display.dispose();
    }
  }
```

Comment: Seems to work OK on macOS.

Comment: You may need to draw the background color in the EraseItem

Answer (score 0):

@greg449:  yes, that seems to work with background drawing on EraseItem

```
      ... 
      case SWT.EraseItem: {
        event.detail &= ~SWT.FOREGROUND;
        event.detail &= ~SWT.HOT;
        event.detail &= ~SWT.SELECTED;
        GC gc = event.gc;      
        gc.fillRectangle(event.x, event.y, event.width, event.height);
        break;
      }
      ...
```

thanks a lot!